# Find a function using definite integral from the second fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need to find a function whose derivative is $\sin x^3$ and whose value at $0$ is $2$. I have the solution and understand its integral part formally. What I don't understand formally (but do understand intuitively) is why we add $2$ to the definite integral. See the correct solution below.

$$\int_{0}^x \sin(t^3)dt + 2 $$

The result I have obtained myself is the definite integral according to the Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you don't have the $+2$, and just the formula 
$$\int_0^x \sin(t^3) \, dt
$$
Now, the requirement is that the "value at $0$ is $2$". In other words when you plug $x=0$ into this formula, you are supposed to get $2$. So, let's plug in $x=0$ and see what we get:
$$\int_0^0 \sin(t^3) \, dt
$$
Well, that's equal to $0$. In fact $\int_a^a f(t) \, dt = 0$ no matter what the function $f(t)$ is and no matter what $a$ is.

Oops! We were supposed to get $2$, not $0$.

How do we fix that? By adding $2$:
$$\int_0^x \sin(t^3) \, dt + 2
$$
And now, when you plug in $x=0$ to this formula, you get $2$, as required.

Comment: this is super close to what my intuition here is. I was confused when integrating from 0 to 0 was giving me 2 in accordance with the conditions given, because it gives 0 at all times. Thanks for giving me a hand here.